# exclude all except from preg_match

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

If I have a string like

```
$string = 'the grey fox [[function name]] jumped over the moon';
```

How do I remove everything from the string **except** what is found in the **square brackets**? I can `find and replace` the code inside the square brackets like so:

```
$page_function = preg_replace('#\[\[(.*?)\]\]#', '', $string);
```

I need a way to **`inverse the preg_replace`** so I can replace all EXCEPT the code found in the `preg_replace`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are most likely looking for is the complement function preg_match http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Example from interactive shell:

```
php > $string = 'the grey fox [[function name]] jumped over the moon';
php > preg_match('#\[\[(.*?)\]\]#', $string, $m);
php > var_dump($m);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "[[function name]]"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "function name"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! adding the $m var to the preg_match function then using $m[0] worked perfectly!